# Error: Dialog.addIFrame is not a function

Tags: iframe, plugins, dialog, ckeditor

I tried to create a plugin for CKEditor 4.4

The main idea was to have a button in the toolbar, when you click on it, there will be a dialog window with its content loaded from another site.

I thought the Dialog.addIframe() function would help and put it into my plugin.js like this:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'insertVariable', {
  icons: 'insertvariable',
  init: function( editor ) {
    for(e in CKEDITOR.dialog){
      alert(e + "   " + editor[e]);
    }
    alert(CKEDITOR.dialog.addIframe());
    editor.addCommand( 'varDialog', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'varDialog' ) );

    CKEDITOR.dialog.addIframe('varDialog','varDialog','http://www.cksource.com/',500,400);

    editor.ui.addButton( 'insertVariable', {
      label: 'Insert Variable',
      command: 'varDialog',
      icon: this.path + 'icons/InsertVariable.gif'
    });

  }
});
```

When I run the code, I get the following error in the console:

```
addiframe is not a function
```

I am using the latest version of CKEditor (4.4 Full Version) and have the Iframe plugin running. All other plugins work just fine, only this one with an Iframe is causing problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved: there was another plugin i had to install: iframe Dialog plugin. This one was nowhere mentioned. With this plugin all my dialogs shown up as they should

Comment: How? How did you install it?